# Consuming custom List<object> in FoxPro from webservice

Tags: .net, web-services, webservice-client, foxpro

I have a Visual Studio 2010 web service project that creates a custom class and binds my sql query results to that object as a `List<object>` and returns that. We're trying to figure out how to consume that object in FoxPro. My object is as follows -

```
public class CustomObject
{
   public string Name;
   public int Id;
}
```

Then that gets converted to a `List<CustomObject>` to contain all the results that are returned. Thanks.

Comment: "in FoxPro" << there's your first problem! amirite?? Just kidding. But only partially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at the article Rick Strahl has written on this very subject: [Using Visual FoxPro to call
.Net Web Services for Data Access](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/foxpronetwebservices/foxpronetwebservices.asp)

Comment: @john-saunders I saw 'Last Update: February 14, 2009' and thought that was reasonable, especially as FoxPro's final release was in 2007. Perhaps you have something better to contribute, or is downvoting your way of contributing to the community?

Comment: I am confused by John's downvote.  Is it because Stuart linked to another site or is it because the answer is wrong? In my opinion, Rick Strahl is highly skilled in both .NET and Visual FoxPro.  Merds, I agree with Stuart that you should look at what Rick wrote and see if it applies to your problem.